# Spring boot embedded kafka throws error BeanCreationException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have a test case with following configured kafka properties:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EmbeddedKafka(controlledShutdown = true, topics = {"topic1", "topic2", "topic3"})
class Name {}
```

Here is the build error i get when running the test case above:

```
Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:242)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:961)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.LogDirProp(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

Here is the POM file with spring kafka & kafka-client dependency which is likely causing the error:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Solution:
Please refer to this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

````
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `spring-Kafka` version is not compatible with Apache Kafka client `3.0`. You need still coming `2.8` and Spring Boot `2.6`.

On the other hand you don’t need newer client even if you use newer broker . Although the story is about embedded testing, so I fully doubt you need to worry about any client, unless it is something transitive from Spring for Apache Kafka…

Comment: The reason behind excluding and re-importing newer Kafka-clients is because the there is a security vulnerability in my project stemming from the kafka-clients version compiled from spring-kafka. What versions would you recommend for both to resolve this error?

Comment: OK. What is that vulnerability, please? Would you mind to share a link for that and its fix in Apache Kafka? Anyway I don't think it impacts testing somehow. You may consider to have a new `kafka-clients`  version for production code, but still use a transitive version for test scope.

Comment: Here's a link to the vulnerability im facing: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-38153.

Comment: Thanks. It said it is fixed in the `2.8.1` as well. Did you try with that one? `3.0.0` client is too aggressive for the current `spring-kafka-2.7.x`

Comment: Please see the documentation for how to override the kafka-clients (and associated jars for the embedded broker) version.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: Yes, I tried 2.8.1 and the issue still persists.

Comment: OK. So, as I said before: try to keep the current `2.7.1` for testing and move production to `2.8.1`. I doubt the security vulnerability affect you somehow when you test against embedded Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

Here are the versions that worked for me:
Spring-kafka -> 2.7.7
Kafka-clients -> 2.8.1

I had to override the dependencies mentioned in the article @GaryRussell shared.